# Use Ffmpeg on android with linux commands

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I'm new programmer for android. I want to use `ffmpeg` with android.

But my question is can I use `ffpmeg` on android programming with Linux commands?
for example use this `ffmpeg` code :

```
ffmpeg -framerate 1/5 -i img%03d.png -c:v libx264 -r 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4
```

on android programming??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can. Build your ffmpeg binary with `pie` support for Android version above API 16.

Use `Runtime` or `Process` to execute the commands.

In my old experiences, commands can not access external storage resources. So be careful not directly manipulate external storage files (input or output) in ffmpeg command.

Comment: hello, can you give me your email please? I have some questions